# What is this plant that sprouted when I planted pepper seeds?

Tags: identification, germination

I thought I had bought shishito pepper seeds and this grew.  What is it?

[image]

Comment: Where do  you live and what kind of soil did you plant the seeds in? If you used soil from your garden, it's possible that it's something found naturally in your area. Even if you used sterile potting soil, a "local" seed could have landed and grown in the pot.

Comment: Thanks-- Live in Central Jersey- I used potting soil to plant the seedling and came up quick. I bought the seeds from "High Mowing Organic Seeds"  Im thinking this is not a pepper- and nothing ive seen before.

Comment: How long ago did it sprout?

Answer (score 2):

First thing that jumped out were the 'spots'...this is Persicaria...same family as knotweed.  This is called or at least its cousins, Lady's Thumb.  Thus the thumb print in the middle of the leaf. This is a normal weed, edible, actually. Prettiest one I've ever seen...grin! Can you provide another picture, a close-up of one of the joints? It'd help identify the species/variety.
[Persicaria vulgaris](http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/weeds/plants/lady_thumb.htm://)